# js accordion not working IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

first question ever on this page. I have a animated css/js accordion which I took from this page http://codepen.io/chriswrightdesign/pen/cmanI and I have just implemented it in a jsp web application.

It is working very well in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11. But not showing up properly in IE 9. As far as I know there are some js components (classList, setAttribute and querySelectorAll) which I need to polyfill in order to get the functionality working correctly in that last navigator.

To be honest, I don't have the slightest idea on how to polyfill this js code. So I would really apreciate if anyone could help me.

```
    //uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function(){
    var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
  touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
  pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

        setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty){
        el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
    };
    setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded){
        switch(expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
                break;
        }
    };
//function
switchAccordion = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if(thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
    };
    for (var i=0,len=accordionToggles.length; i<len; i++) {
        if(touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if(pointerSupported){
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

Comment: It seems like CodePen doesn't work on IE9. I've copied your code to here http://jsfiddle.net/d4uxLuts/ and it seems like it works. What is the expected behaviour? I don't see any typical accordeon behaviour, in IE9 or otherwise.

Comment: What is happening in fact is that in IE9 all the elements of the accordion show extended and static. When you click on the elements the animation simply doesn't work. It seems  is not possible to reproduce this on jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh sure, it's entirely possible the animations don't work in IE9. The animations are CSS transitions right? If you want to polyfill that you're going to need a lot of JS code.

Comment: Screw IE9? Anything we develop here is for IE10 +. Animations are a nightmare in IE9, mostly requiring a lot of JS to get them working properly. If IE9 is a requirement you'd be better off creating a fallback design that doesn't include an accordion.

Comment: That's right, in this case the animation works with css transitions. So, do you think it would be more viable to implement this functionality with a css or js code supported on IE9?

Answer (score 0):

For one, [classList](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) is not supported in IE9, so you are definitely going to have to build a fallback if a requirement is IE9 support.